# Can we say for any given interval in $\mathbb R$ that every point in this interval is accumulation point?

Tags: real-numbers

Accumulation point means briefly that if $x_0$ is acc. point in set $S$  then for any given $\epsilon>0$, $((x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon ) \cap S )\setminus\{x_0\} \not = \emptyset$

My reasoning is, since every **(open)** interval is open set for every $x$ in the set we can ball containing $x$ inside the set(interval). This means $\epsilon>0$, $((x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon ) \cap S )\setminus\{x_0\} \not = \emptyset$. Is it wrong then is there any counterexample ?

Can we generalize it to $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: The condition for accumulation point is $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)\cap S$ contains some point $x\ne x_0$.

Comment: $\epsilon>0$, $((x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon ) \cap S )\setminus\{x_0\} \not = \emptyset$ editted

Comment: _"since every interval is open set"_: most certainly not

Answer (score 1):

Your claim is true. But note that every interval is not necessarily an open set.